# Android: How to move my canvas drawable shapes

Tags: java, android

1. I am trying to implement a Drawing Application in Android where the user should be able to select and move the drawn shapes.
   Currently, I have statically drawn some rects and text on my Drawing Canvas.
2. I want to select (draw borders on the selected shape) and move the drawn shapes in `onTouch` events of the drawing canvas.

```
package com.android.graphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PathEffect;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CanvasView extends View {
    public enum Mode {
        DRAW,
        TEXT,
        ERASER;
    }

    public enum Drawer {
        PEN,
        LINE,
        RECTANGLE,
        CIRCLE,
        ELLIPSE,
        QUADRATIC_BEZIER,
        QUBIC_BEZIER;
    }

    private Canvas canvas = null;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;
    private List<Path> pathLists = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private List<Paint> paintLists = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    private final Paint emptyPaint = new Paint();
    private int baseColor = Color.WHITE;
    // for Undo, Redo
    private int historyPointer = 0;
    // Flags
    private Mode mode = Mode.DRAW;
    private Drawer drawer = Drawer.PEN;
    private boolean isDown = false;
    // for Paint
    private Paint.Style paintStyle = Paint.Style.STROKE;
    private int paintStrokeColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int paintFillColor = Color.BLACK;
    private float paintStrokeWidth = 3F;
    private int opacity = 255;
    private float blur = 0F;
    private Paint.Cap lineCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND;
    private PathEffect drawPathEffect = null;
    // for Text
    private String text = "";
    private Typeface fontFamily = Typeface.DEFAULT;
    private float fontSize = 32F;
    private Paint.Align textAlign = Paint.Align.RIGHT;  // fixed
    private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    private float textX = 0F;
    private float textY = 0F;
    // for Drawer
    private float startX = 0F;
    private float startY = 0F;
    private float controlX = 0F;
    private float controlY = 0F;

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setup();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setup();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        this.pathLists.add(new Path());
        this.paintLists.add(this.createPaint());
        this.historyPointer++;
        this.textPaint.setARGB(0, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    private Paint createPaint() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(this.paintStyle);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(this.paintStrokeWidth);
        paint.setStrokeCap(this.lineCap);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);  // fixed
        // for Text
        if (this.mode == Mode.TEXT) {
            paint.setTypeface(this.fontFamily);
            paint.setTextSize(this.fontSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(this.textAlign);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(0F);
        }
        if (this.mode == Mode.ERASER) {
            // Eraser
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            paint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        } else {
            // Otherwise
            paint.setColor(this.paintStrokeColor);
            paint.setShadowLayer(this.blur, 0F, 0F, this.paintStrokeColor);
            paint.setAlpha(this.opacity);
            paint.setPathEffect(this.drawPathEffect);
        }
        return paint;
    }

    private Path createPath(MotionEvent event) {
        Path path = new Path();
        // Save for ACTION_MOVE
        this.startX = event.getX();
        this.startY = event.getY();
        path.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
        return path;
    }

    private void updateHistory(Path path) {
        if (this.historyPointer == this.pathLists.size()) {
            this.pathLists.add(path);
            this.paintLists.add(this.createPaint());
            this.historyPointer++;
        } else {
            // On the way of Undo or Redo
            this.pathLists.set(this.historyPointer, path);
            this.paintLists.set(this.historyPointer, this.createPaint());
            this.historyPointer++;

            for (int i = this.historyPointer, size = this.paintLists.size(); i < size; i++) {
                this.pathLists.remove(this.historyPointer);
                this.paintLists.remove(this.historyPointer);
            }
        }
    }

    private Path getCurrentPath() {
        return this.pathLists.get(this.historyPointer - 1);
    }

    private void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
        if (this.text.length() <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.mode == Mode.TEXT) {
            this.textX = this.startX;
            this.textY = this.startY;
            this.textPaint = this.createPaint();
        }
        float textX = this.textX;
        float textY = this.textY;
        Paint paintForMeasureText = new Paint();
        // Line break automatically
        float textLength = paintForMeasureText.measureText(this.text);
        float lengthOfChar = textLength / (float) this.text.length();
        float restWidth = this.canvas.getWidth() - textX;  // text-align : right
        int numChars = (lengthOfChar <= 0) ? 1 : (int) Math.floor((double) (restWidth / lengthOfChar));  // The number of characters at 1 line
        int modNumChars = (numChars < 1) ? 1 : numChars;
        float y = textY;
        for (int i = 0, len = this.text.length(); i < len; i += modNumChars) {
            String substring = "";
            if ((i + modNumChars) < len) {
                substring = this.text.substring(i, (i + modNumChars));
            } else {
                substring = this.text.substring(i, len);
            }
            y += this.fontSize;
            canvas.drawText(substring, textX, y, this.textPaint);
        }
    }

    private void onActionDown(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (this.mode) {
            case DRAW:
            case ERASER:
                if ((this.drawer != Drawer.QUADRATIC_BEZIER) && (this.drawer != Drawer.QUBIC_BEZIER)) {
                    // Oherwise
                    this.updateHistory(this.createPath(event));
                    this.isDown = true;
                } else {
                    // Bezier
                    if ((this.startX == 0F) && (this.startY == 0F)) {
                        // The 1st tap
                        this.updateHistory(this.createPath(event));
                    } else {
                        // The 2nd tap
                        this.controlX = event.getX();
                        this.controlY = event.getY();

                        this.isDown = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TEXT:
                this.startX = event.getX();
                this.startY = event.getY();

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    private void onActionMove(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (this.mode) {
            case DRAW:
            case ERASER:
                if ((this.drawer != Drawer.QUADRATIC_BEZIER) && (this.drawer != Drawer.QUBIC_BEZIER)) {
                    if (!isDown) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Path path = this.getCurrentPath();
                    switch (this.drawer) {
                        case PEN:
                            path.lineTo(x, y);
                            break;
                        case LINE:
                            path.reset();
                            path.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
                            path.lineTo(x, y);
                            break;
                        case RECTANGLE:
                            path.reset();
                            float left = Math.min(this.startX, x);
                            float right = Math.max(this.startX, x);
                            float top = Math.min(this.startY, y);
                            float bottom = Math.max(this.startY, y);
                            path.addRect(left, top, right, bottom, Path.Direction.CCW);
                            break;
                        case CIRCLE:
                            double distanceX = Math.abs((double) (this.startX - x));
                            double distanceY = Math.abs((double) (this.startX - y));
                            double radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX, 2.0) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2.0));
                            path.reset();
                            path.addCircle(this.startX, this.startY, (float) radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
                            break;
                        case ELLIPSE:
                            RectF rect = new RectF(this.startX, this.startY, x, y);
                            path.reset();
                            path.addOval(rect, Path.Direction.CCW);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!isDown) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Path path = this.getCurrentPath();
                    path.reset();
                    path.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
                    path.quadTo(this.controlX, this.controlY, x, y);
                }
                break;
            case TEXT:
                this.startX = x;
                this.startY = y;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onActionUp(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isDown) {
            this.startX = 0F;
            this.startY = 0F;
            this.isDown = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Before "drawPath"
        canvas.drawColor(this.baseColor);
        if (this.bitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0F, 0F, emptyPaint);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.historyPointer; i++) {
            Path path = this.pathLists.get(i);
            Paint paint = this.paintLists.get(i);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        this.drawText(canvas);
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.onActionDown(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                this.onActionMove(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.onActionUp(event);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // Re draw
        this.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public Mode getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    public void setMode(Mode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public Drawer getDrawer() {
        return this.drawer;
    }

    public void setDrawer(Drawer drawer) {
        this.drawer = drawer;
    }

    public boolean canUndo() {
        return this.historyPointer > 1;
    }

    public boolean canRedo() {
        return this.historyPointer < this.pathLists.size();
    }

    public boolean undo() {
        if (canUndo()) {
            this.historyPointer--;
            this.invalidate();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean redo() {
        if (canRedo()) {
            this.historyPointer++;
            this.invalidate();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0F, 0F);
        path.addRect(0F, 0F, 3000F, 3000F, Path.Direction.CCW);
        path.close();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        if (this.historyPointer == this.pathLists.size()) {
            this.pathLists.add(path);
            this.paintLists.add(paint);
            this.historyPointer++;
        } else {
            // On the way of Undo or Redo
            this.pathLists.set(this.historyPointer, path);
            this.paintLists.set(this.historyPointer, paint);
            this.historyPointer++;

            for (int i = this.historyPointer, size = this.paintLists.size(); i < size; i++) {
                this.pathLists.remove(this.historyPointer);
                this.paintLists.remove(this.historyPointer);
            }
        }
        this.text = "";
        // Clear
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getBaseColor() {
        return this.baseColor;
    }

    public void setBaseColor(int color) {
        this.baseColor = color;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Paint.Style getPaintStyle() {
        return this.paintStyle;
    }

    public void setPaintStyle(Paint.Style style) {
        this.paintStyle = style;
    }

    public int getPaintStrokeColor() {
        return this.paintStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeColor(int color) {
        this.paintStrokeColor = color;
    }

    public int getPaintFillColor() {
        return this.paintFillColor;
    }

    public void setPaintFillColor(int color) {
        this.paintFillColor = color;
    }

    public float getPaintStrokeWidth() {
        return this.paintStrokeWidth;
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeWidth(float width) {
        if (width >= 0) {
            this.paintStrokeWidth = width;
        } else {
            this.paintStrokeWidth = 3F;
        }
    }

    public int getOpacity() {
        return this.opacity;
    }

    public void setOpacity(int opacity) {
        if ((opacity >= 0) && (opacity <= 255)) {
            this.opacity = opacity;
        } else {
            this.opacity = 255;
        }
    }

    public float getBlur() {
        return this.blur;
    }

    public void setBlur(float blur) {
        if (blur >= 0) {
            this.blur = blur;
        } else {
            this.blur = 0F;
        }
    }

    public Paint.Cap getLineCap() {
        return this.lineCap;
    }

    public void setLineCap(Paint.Cap cap) {
        this.lineCap = cap;
    }

    public PathEffect getDrawPathEffect() {
        return drawPathEffect;
    }

    public void setDrawPathEffect(PathEffect drawPathEffect) {
        this.drawPathEffect = drawPathEffect;
    }

    public float getFontSize() {
        return this.fontSize;
    }

    public void setFontSize(float size) {
        if (size >= 0F) {
            this.fontSize = size;
        } else {
            this.fontSize = 32F;
        }
    }

    public Typeface getFontFamily() {
        return this.fontFamily;
    }

    public void setFontFamily(Typeface face) {
        this.fontFamily = face;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());
    }

    public Bitmap getScaleBitmap(int w, int h) {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.getDrawingCache(), w, h, true);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void drawBitmap(byte[] byteArray) {
        this.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length));
    }

    public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap, CompressFormat format, int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(CompressFormat format, int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.getBitmap().compress(format, quality, byteArrayOutputStream);

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray() {
        return this.getBitmapAsByteArray(CompressFormat.PNG, 100);
    }
}
```